# alsa-utils + ndk-build not working

Tags: android, android-ndk, alsa, ndk-build

I have source code alsa-utils-1.0.27.2 from http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page
I need for build it to my android:

> user@vbUbuntu1204:~/Android-alsa/alsa-utils$ cat jni/Android.mk

```
ifeq ($(strip $(BOARD_USES_ALSA_AUDIO)),true)
ifeq ($(strip $(BUILD_WITH_ALSA_UTILS)),true)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

#
# Build aplay command
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    -fPIC -D_POSIX_SOURCE \
    -DALSA_CONFIG_DIR=\"/system/usr/share/alsa\" \
    -DALSA_PLUGIN_DIR=\"/system/usr/lib/alsa-lib\" \
    -DALSA_DEVICE_DIRECTORY=\"/dev/snd/\"

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/android \
    external/alsa-lib/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    aplay/aplay.c

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
LOCAL_MODULE := alsa_aplay

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libaudio \
    libc

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

#
# Build alsactl command
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    -fPIC -D_POSIX_SOURCE \
    -DALSA_CONFIG_DIR=\"/system/usr/share/alsa\" \
    -DALSA_PLUGIN_DIR=\"/system/usr/lib/alsa-lib\" \
    -DALSA_DEVICE_DIRECTORY=\"/dev/snd/\"

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/android \
    external/alsa-lib/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    alsactl/alsactl.c \
    alsactl/init_parse.c \
    alsactl/state.c \
    alsactl/utils.c

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
LOCAL_MODULE := alsa_ctl

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libaudio \
    libc

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

#
# Build amixer command
#

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := \
    -fPIC -D_POSIX_SOURCE \
    -DALSA_CONFIG_DIR=\"/system/usr/share/alsa\" \
    -DALSA_PLUGIN_DIR=\"/system/usr/lib/alsa-lib\" \
    -DALSA_DEVICE_DIRECTORY=\"/dev/snd/\"

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/android \
    external/alsa-lib/include

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    amixer/amixer.c

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := debug
LOCAL_MODULE := alsa_amixer

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libaudio \
    libc

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

ALSAINIT_DIR := $(TARGET_OUT)/usr/share/alsa/init

files := $(addprefix $(ALSAINIT_DIR)/,00main default hda help info test)

$(files): PRIVATE_MODULE := alsactl_initdir
$(files): $(ALSAINIT_DIR)/%: $(LOCAL_PATH)/alsactl/init/% | $(ACP)
    $(transform-prebuilt-to-target)

ALL_PREBUILT += $(files)

endif
endif
```

> user@vbUbuntu1204:~/Android-alsa/alsa-utils$ cat jni/Application.mk

```
APP_PROJECT_PATH := /home/user/Android-alsa/alsa-utils/
NDK_PROJECT_PATH := ~/android-ndk-r9d/
```

> > user@vbUbuntu1204:~/Android-alsa/alsa-utils$
> >     ../../android-ndk-r9d/ndk-build
>
> /home/user/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-all.mk:89: Android NDK:
>   WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!

How to correct thish?

Comment: #ifeq ($(strip $(BOARD_USES_ALSA_AUDIO)),true)
 #ifeq ($(strip $(BUILD_WITH_ALSA_UTILS)),true)
 ....
  #endif
  #endif

Comment: So, you are OK now? Run `ndk-build BOARD_USES_ALSA_AUDIO=true BUILD_WITH_ALSA_UTILS=true`.

Comment: no, i also build liasound.so, and build utils with key in Android.mk LIBASOUND_PATH=$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libasound/libs/armeabi-v7a/libasound.so. All ok!