# How to build Alsa Utils with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, alsa

My goal is to compile amixer from [alsa-utils-1.0.29](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) using Android NDK to an executable I can use on Android device.
I can't find a way to build it using ndk-build nor can I find any documentation on how to achieve this.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

**Edit:** 
I tried cross-compiling alsa-lib and alsa-utils on Ubunto using [this guide](http://www.programering.com/a/MTN0UDMwATk.html), but result amixer does not run on Android (says no such file or directory).

When I use ndk-build amixer does not compile (keeps complaining on undefined references).

**Edit 2:**

The steps I did that failed were as following:

 - Downloaded alsa-lib and alsa-utils from alsa project site

 - Compiled alsa-lib using Android.mk based on [this Android.mk](https://github.com/michaelwu/alsa-lib/blob/master/Android.mk) - succeeded

 - Compiled alsa-utils based on this SO question: [alsa-utils + ndk-build not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524943/alsa-utils-ndk-build-not-working)

 - At first I constantly got errors saying there is no rule for building amixer.o. **Only replacing $(LOCAL_PATH) with hard-coded path resolved it**

 - Now, when compiling - although Android.mk points to all required includes, I got lots of undefined reference errors such as: "undefined reference to 'snd_ctl_card_info_sizeof'"

What is the way to build alsa-utils in a way it can be used on Android?

Comment: You are likely to run into a huge variety of problems, ranging from access permissions, to install location issues to trying to talk to APIs that may not exist, to missing libraries you would need to build against.  What are you actually trying to accomplish by this project?  Likely it is not the best approach.

Comment: My goal is to have an amixer executable (sometimes renamed to alsa_amixer by Android.mk files) that I can use on android device (similar to what AlsaMixer app installs on /system/xbin when selecting to install Alsa). I would settle for the executable itself but I can't find one that comes with clear license terms so I can know I can use it

Comment: ALSA is not a public API of Android; if you want to *assume* it is actually there on devices interesting to you you will have to figure out how to supply (stub?) dependencies or ignore their absence during build, and hope that they will actually be found on the device.  Generally, going outside of stable APIs is risky; more so when you are new to doing development and unprepared to work through the resulting error messages one by one.  As for asking here, questions without precise *specifics* of the problem get closed, not answered.

Comment: I'm asking about a proven to be possible goal. There are as I mentioned before applications that use alsa_amixer executable. My question is how to build alsa-utils using ndk-build, because when using Android.mk from several repositories that aim to port alsa-utils for android, the build fails

Comment: That is not the type of question this site handles.  **Specific** error messages could be, but your post doesn't include any.

Comment: This is more of an how-to question, not how-to-fix or what-went-wrong question. I can post build errors but I think they will not help to make the question more eligible because I am pretty sure the build itself is not done correctly, which is initially what I asked about.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not for "how to" questions but rather for specifics, so yes, you need to post the actual errors you are encountering if you want help with them.  Fundamentally though, your problem is that you are trying to do something Android is not intended to support - that's not to say it will be impossible (on a root-hacked device) but that you will have an unphill battle.  The undefined references are symptomatic of that - as you aren't supposed to link against ALSA, support for it is missing from the NDK and you will have to provide substitutes or use the allow undefined flag.

Comment: I'll update the question with more specific errors

Comment: After updates, still off-topic for the site.  Read this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic